# Code for parsing a character buffer

Tags: c, parsing, buffer

I want to parse a character buffer and store it in a data structure.
The 1st 4 bytes of the buffer specifies the name, the 2nd four bytes specifies the length (n) of the value and the next n bytes specifies the value.

eg: char *buff = "aaaa0006francebbbb0005swisscccc0013unitedkingdom"

I want to extract the name and the value from the buffer and store it a data structure.
eg: char *name = "aaaa"
    char *value = "france"

```
char *name = "bbbb"
char *value = "swiss"
```

After storing, I should be able to access the value from the data structure by using the name.
What data structure should I use?

EDIT (from comment):
I tried the following:

```
struct sample { 
    char string[4]; 
    int length[4]; 
    char *value; }; 

struct sample s[100]; 

while ( *buf ) { 
    memcpy(s[i].string, buf, 4); 
    memcpy(s[i].length, buf+4, 4); 
    memcpy(s[i].value, buf+8, s.length); 
    buf += (8+s.length); 
}
```

Should I call memcpy thrice? Is there a way to do it by calling memcpy only once?

Comment: You should use a string. Congratulations, you're already done.

Comment: In this case, value is not 4 bytes .. see france and swiss

Comment: @Sibi : length of the value is not 4 bytes.. 4 bytes of the buffer is used for specifying the length of the value

Comment: @linuxfreak i am talking about this in your question. "the 3rd four bytes specifies the value"

Comment: @Vicky:I tried the following:

struct sample 
{
char string[4];
int length[4];
char *value;
};

struct sample s[100];

while ( *buf )
{
   memcpy(s[i].string, buf, 4);
   memcpy(s[i].length, buf+4, 4);
   memcpy(s[i].value, buf+8, s.length);
   buf += (8+s.length);
}

Should I call memcpy thrice? Is there a way to do it by calling memcpy only once?

Comment: @linuxfreak, better to edit that additional info into your post so it can be formatted!

Comment: @Sibi: You are right. It should be "3rd n bytes"

Comment: OK, in that example: you can't memcpy into `value` since you haven't declared any memory space for it - it's just an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: ...and your length handling is incorrect! It's clearly not four bytes representing an integer, rather four digits which represents the length...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not using *memcpy* at all?

```
typedef struct sample { 
    char name[4]; 
    union 
    {
        char length_data[4];
        unsigned int length; 
    };
    char value[]; 
} sample_t; 

const char * sample_data = "aaaa\6\0\0\0francebbbb\5\0\0\0swisscccc\15\0\0\0unitedkingdom";

void main()
{
    sample_t * s[10];
    const char * current = sample_data;
    int i = 0;

    while (*current)
    {
        s[i] = (sample_t *) current;
        current += (s[i])->length + 8;
        i++;
    }

    // Here, s[0], s[1] and s[2] should be set properly

    return;
}
```

Now, you never specify clearly whether the 4 bytes representing the length contain the string representation or the actual binary data; if it's four characters that needs to run through *atoi()* or similar then you need to do some post-processing like

```
    s[i]->length = atoi(s[i]->length_data)
```

before the struct is usable, which in turn means that the source data must be writeable and probably copied locally. But even then you should be able to copy the whole input buffer at once instead of chopping it up.

Also, please note that this relies on anything using this struct honors the length field rather than treating the value field as a null-terminated string.

Finally, using binary integer data like this is obviously architecture-dependent with all the implications that follows.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on your newly provided info, this will work better:

```
struct sample { 
    char string[4]; 
    int length; 
    char *value; }; 

struct sample s[100]; 

while ( *buf && i < 100) { 

    memcpy(s[i].string, buf, 4); 

    s[i].length = atoi(buf+4); 

    s[i].value = malloc(s[i].length);
    if (s[i].value)
    {
         memcpy(s[i].value, buf+8, s[i].length); 
    }
    buf += (8+s[i].length); 
    i++;
```

}

Comment: After I fill the array of structures, if I want to access the value corresponding to a given name, I have to loop over the entire array, right? I don't want to do that. I want to get the value just by querying the name. That's why I asked if there is any other data structure(like hashtable) I can use other than structure

Comment: I replied to your comment on my other answer (which I provided before you added the extra info). Now that answer is obsolete I will delete it and put my reply to your comment here in a moment...

Comment: There's no built-in hashtable or dictionary-like functionality, although there are doubtless open-source implementations (or write your own). Under the hood it would still have to search over the entire array or list to get the data you need.

Comment: Suppose I parse the buffer and put them in a hashtable instead of array of structures, considering complexity for accessing data from hash table is O(1), isn't accessing values faster than accessing from array of structures?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've only just understood exactly what you meant. Yes, if you implement (or use someone else's implementation of) a hashtable, it will be O(1) access.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that:
I will define a variable length structure, like this:

```
typedef struct { 
    char string[4]; 
    int length[4]; 
    char value[0] } sample;
```

now , while parsing, read the string and length into temporary variables.
then, allocate enough memory for the structure.

```
uint32_t string = * ( ( uint32_t * ) buffer );
uint32_t length = * ( ( uint32_t * ) buffer + 4);
sample * = malloc(sizeof(sample) + length);
// Check here for malloc errors...
 * ( (uint32_t *) sample->string) = string;
 * ( (uint32_t *) sample->length) = length;
memcpy(sample->value, ( buffer + 8 ), length);
```

This approach, keeps the entire context of the buffer in one continuous memory structure.
I use it all the time.

Comment: You can actually remove the variables, but it's easier on the eyes and mind to keep it (for clarity)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have slightly modified your code.  Will this work? 
uint32_t length = *((uint32_t *)buffer + 4);
sample *s = malloc(sizeof(sample) + length);
int32_t entrySize = 8+length;
memcpy(s, buffer, entrySize); 
buffer += entrySize;

Comment: If you find any of the answers useful, please accept one of them. Pressing the up arrow next to an answer is a show of graditude for tje person who written tje answer.

Comment: Ok.. I didn't know about it.  Will do.